Ubuntu 24.04 stuck booting linux kernel 6.8.0 on Thinkpad T490 Intel (works with kernel 5.15.0)
I upgrade my Thinkpad T490 with Intel CPU from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04 today. When booting with the new default kernel 6.8.0-45 the boot is stuck with the following console message very soon.

I have a fully encrypted harddisc and the decryption password dialog is not even reached. Booting is stuck with 1 or 2 secs immediately.
I have already run sudo update-initramfs -u to update the initramfs (not really sure this is needed or the problem):
$ sudo update-initramfs -u
[sudo] Passwort für xxx: 
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-45-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-2
I: (/dev/mapper/vgcherries-lvcherriesswap)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.

Booting 24.04 works without problems with "old" 5.15.0-122-generic kernel.
PS My hardware:
$ lspci 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Coffee Lake HOST and DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation WhiskeyLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics 620]
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0b)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Thermal Controller (rev 30)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Controller (rev 30)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Shared SRAM (rev 30)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] (rev 30)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 30)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SPI Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (6) I219-V (rev 30)
01:00.0 SD Host controller: Genesys Logic, Inc GL9750 SD Host Controller (rev 01)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01)
03:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01)
03:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01)
04:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 NHI (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01)
05:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
06:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
06:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
07:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
08:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
38:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 USB 3.1 Controller (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01)
6c:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Intel Corporation SSD DC P4101/Pro 7600p/760p/E 6100p Series (rev 03)


I am having a similar issue on a T480. Did you find out a solution?
In my case, after waking up from hibernation (opening the lid), it looks like something is off with the graphic card drivers. It cannot restore the display configuration.

@narko Nope, I worked around by setting 5.15.0 kernel version as the default https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/327686/98879
